# Find $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}$ if $x_n \to a$ when $n \to \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

If $x_n \to a$, what can be said about $\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}}$ ?

I do have a solution but I wonder whether there is a more simple way to find the answer.

---

*Solution.*

(1) If $a \neq 0,$ then $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x_{n + 1}}{x_n} = \frac{\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} x_{n+1}}{\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n} = \frac{a}{a} = 1$$

(2) If $a = 0,$ then $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x_{n + 1}}{x_n}$ may not exist.

Consider the sequence $$x_n=\underbrace{\frac{1}{p}}_{\color{grey}{x_1}}, \underbrace{\frac{1}{p}}_{\color{grey}{x_2}}, \underbrace{\frac{1}{p^2}}_{\color{grey}{x_3}}, \underbrace{\frac{1}{p^2}}_{\color{grey}{x_4}}, \cdots,  \underbrace{\frac{1}{p^k}}_{\color{grey}{x_{2k-1}}}, \underbrace{\frac{1}{p^k}}_{\color{grey}{x_{2k}}}, \cdots \space (p>1)$$

We have $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=0$.
But

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x_{2n}}{x_{2n - 1}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\frac1{p^n}}{\frac1{p^n}} = 1$$

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x_{2n+1}}{x_{2n}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\frac1{p^{n+1}}}{\frac1{p^n}} = \frac{1}{p}$$

so the limit of $\displaystyle \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}$ does not exist.

Another example is a stationary sequence $\{x_n\}=0$ which does have a limit $$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}0=0$$ but the limit of $\displaystyle \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}$ does not exist:
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{0}{0}=\frac{0}{0} - undefined$$

(3) Suppose $\displaystyle \frac{x_{n + 1}}{x_n}$ does have a limit and its value is $b.$ Let's prove that $|b|$ must be $\leq 1$. For contradiction, let's suppose that $|b| > 1$. By limit property $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \left| \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} \right| =|b|>1$.
$$\left|\left|\frac{x_{n + 1}}{x_n}\right| - |b|\right| < \epsilon$$

which implies that starting from some $n_{\varepsilon}$ for all $n>n_{\varepsilon}$

$$|b| - \varepsilon < \left|\frac{x_{n + 1}}{x_n} \right|< |b| + \varepsilon$$

Because this must hold for all $\varepsilon$, we can consider those $\varepsilon$ such that $|b| - \varepsilon > 1$. Now we have
$$1<\left|\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} \right|<|b|+\varepsilon$$
$$\left|\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}\right| = \frac{|x_{n+1}|}{|x_n|} > 1$$ for $n > n_{\varepsilon}.$

Now, noting that

$$|x_n| = |x_{n_\varepsilon + 1}| \cdot \frac{|x_{n_\varepsilon + 2}|}{|x_{n_\varepsilon + 1}|} \cdot \frac{|x_{n_\varepsilon + 3}|}{|x_{n_\varepsilon + 2}|} \cdot \ldots \cdot \frac{|x_n|}{|x_{n-1}|}$$

let $\displaystyle \lambda = \min\left\{\frac{|x_{n_\varepsilon + 2}|}{|x_{n_\varepsilon + 1}|}, \frac{|x_{n_\varepsilon + 3}|}{|x_{n_\varepsilon + 2}|}, \ldots, \frac{|x_n|}{|x_{n-1}|}\right\}.$ Because $\displaystyle \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} > 1$ for all $n > n_\varepsilon,$ this means that $\lambda > 1,$ so $$|x_n| > |x_{n_\varepsilon + 1}| \cdot \lambda^{n - (n_\varepsilon + 1)}$$ implies that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} |x_n| \geq \lim_{n \to \infty} \left[ |x_{n_\varepsilon + 1}| \cdot \lambda^{n - (n_\varepsilon + 1)} \space \right]= \frac{|x_{n_\varepsilon + 1}|}{\lambda^{n_\varepsilon + 1}} \cdot \lim_{n \to \infty} \lambda^n = +\infty$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}|x_n|=+\infty$$

However, this contradicts our definition of $\displaystyle a = \lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = 0,$ so by contradiction we must have that $|b| \leq 1.$

**Summary:**

if $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=a \not = 0$, then $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}=1 $;

if $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}x_n = a=0$, then either $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}=b\in [-1,1] $ or the limit doesn't exist.

---

This is my first time here, btw.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Please edit your question to include your solution using [MathJax formatting](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation), not as an image.

Comment: For future reference, it's best not to attach crucial parts of a post as images. I'm working on an answer now but I can try to type that out in the post afterwards if you'd like (although I might need to check with you on some translation stuff - I can't read the language but I think I've understood your argument)

Comment: If $a = 0$, then $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}$ could be anything. For eg, for $x_n = b^{-n}$ where $b > 1$, we have $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} = \frac{1}{b}$, so different values for different b.

Comment: @Kaind, First of all you probably meant $a = 0$, as otherwise the limit must be equal to $1$, and second of all the limit still can't literally be anything, for example it may not equal $2$.

Comment: @Adayah So the OP is asking for an upper bound on the limit? The limit need not even be defined for $a = 0$ for eg: $x_n = 0$

Comment: @Kaind I don't know what exactly OP is asking, but you are welcome to ask them yourself. ;P

Comment: Ok, I'll translate my solution into English and type it using MathJax tomorrow (sorry, it's mid night here). But here is a quick comment:
If $a \not = 0$ then $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} =1$. If $a=0$ then $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}$ might not even exist, but when it does it's always  $ \in [-1,1]$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I've understood your attempt (as best as I can without being able to read the language) and here are my thoughts:

Your first point is correct: if $a \neq 0$ then we must have $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} = \frac{\lim_{n \to \infty} x_{n + 1}}{\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n} = \frac{a}{a} = 1.$ If you'd like we could show this in the epsilon-delta form like this: if $|x_n - a| \leq \epsilon$ for all $n \geq n_0(\epsilon),$ then

$$|x_{n + 1} - x_n| \leq |x_{n + 1} - a| + |x_n - a| \leq 2\epsilon \ \text{for } n \geq n_0(\epsilon)$$

$$|x_n - a| \leq \epsilon \Rightarrow a - \epsilon \leq x_n \leq a + \epsilon \Rightarrow |x_n| \geq a - \epsilon \text{ for } n \geq n_0(\epsilon), \epsilon < a$$

$$\left|\frac{x_{n + 1}}{x_n} - 1\right| = \frac{|x_{n + 1} - x_n|}{|x_n|} \leq \frac{2\epsilon}{a - \epsilon} \text{ for } n \geq n_0(\epsilon)$$

and with a little algebraic manipulation we get that $\left|\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} - 1\right| \leq \epsilon_2$ for all $n \geq n_0\left(\frac{a\epsilon_2}{\epsilon_2 + 2}\right).$

---

For your second point, I agree with your counterexample for the case where $\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}$ need not have a limit when $a = 0$ (and I quite like the counterexample you came up with, good job) but I would justify the lack of existence of the limit a bit differently: rather than taking limits of the terms $\frac{x_{2n}}{x_{2n - 1}}$ and $\frac{x_{2n + 1}}{x_{2n}},$ I would just say that the sequence $b_n = \frac{x_{n + 1}}{x_n}$ oscillates between $1$ and $\frac{1}{p},$ and use that to say there is no limit. In any case you have the right idea, the limit does not exist.

---

For the third part of your argument, where you argue that if the limit exists in the $a = 0$ case then its magnitude must be no more than $1,$ I think you can avoid a little bit of annoyance with $\lambda$ relying on $n$ by tightening your imposed restriction on $\epsilon$: instead of saying there must be an $\epsilon > 0$ such that $|b| - \epsilon > 1$ when $|b| > 1,$ I would instead say there must be an $\epsilon > 0$ such that $|b| - \epsilon > \frac{|b| + 1}{2},$ which will happen when $0 < \epsilon < \frac{|b| - 1}{2}.$ Now you can proceed by proving that $x_n \geq x_{n_0} \cdot \left(\frac{|b| + 1}{2}\right)^{n - n_0}$ for $n \geq n_0,$ and from there your argument regarding comparing $x_n$ to a divergent exponential function follows.

---

Overall, good work. It's clear you know what you're doing, there are just a few spots I think things could be tightened up.

Comment: Thanks! Already love this forum. Never got answers to my questions so quickly before. I'll try what you suggested and post (tomorrow) in MathJax solution that includes dealing with $\lambda$ and another one with what you suggested.

Comment: @Cakeice Glad it helped - should I continue with my translation attempt of your original solution attempt?

Comment: I'll add a completely translated version of my solution tomorrow.

Comment: @Cakeice Alright - for the convenience of other users I'm still going to add my attempt if you don't mind. Also it might save you some time having to rewrite some stuff

Comment: I'm always happy to see other solutions here.